# Swype in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm doing the program and wanted to add swiping screen with your finger, I did it but for some reason it does not work on my phone with Android 2.3.3, but in the browser, all works fine. Can you tell what's the problem?

here is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>jQuery Mobile test page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />  -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var pageSeq = ['page1','page2','page3','page4'];
    var currentPage = 0;
    var bindSwipeEvents = function() {
        $(".ui-page").swipeleft(function() {
            console.log(pageSeq.length + ",current:"+currentPage);
            if(currentPage==pageSeq.length) { return; }
            currentPage++;
            $.mobile.changePage( $('#'+pageSeq[currentPage]), 
                             { transition: "slide", reverse:false});
        });

        $(".ui-page").swiperight(function() {
            if(currentPage==0) { return; }
            currentPage--;
            $.mobile.changePage( $('#'+pageSeq[currentPage]), 
                             { transition: "slide", reverse:true});
        });
    };

    $( '.ui-page' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
        bindSwipeEvents();
    });
    bindSwipeEvents();
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.6.1.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <h3> Page 1 </h3>            
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <h3>Page 2</h3>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <h3>Page 3</h3>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <h3>Page 4</h3>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-touch events such as swipe and pinch don’t work in the android browser in the majority of android 2.x ROMs ([see here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909)).

However, you can re-enable these events and therefore use them in phonegap apps on android 2.x devices using [this workaround](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill/).

I've used this in my phonegap app and successfully tested it on android 2.2 using the [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) library to do the event listening.

Comment: i'm try this, but my phone dont responding for my touches and swiping, what my problem? Maybe phonegap version is old? or i dont now...

Comment: what version of phonegap are you using? I'm using [2.1.0](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/2.1.0). Try installing [this test APK](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill/raw/b4f3f1e214360467cd3345cab8531a7194616454/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill-DemoApp.apk) for the workaround and see if multi-touch works on your phone.

Comment: I tried your code above on a phone with android 2.3.3 using phonegap (cordova) 2.1.0 and it works fine (if you swipe between the header and footer). I still recommend hammer.js or a similar library for multi-touch event handling in phonegap.